# How Should I find Android id from android tv settings without using code

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm currently in the process of developing an Android TV app. Utilizing the Android ID, I'm assigning ads to specific TVs. Presently, I'm retrieving the TV ID programmatically. However, the client prefers to obtain the Android ID from settings, so I'm aiming to implement this change to align with their preference.

I want to get android id from tv settings